# SERIAL during insertion of tables

Tags: postgresql

Here are my two tables and my trying to insert the data for those two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE instructor (
 id SERIAL,
 ensemble_proficiency BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
 person_number VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
 first_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
 last_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE(person_number)
);

ALTER TABLE instructor ADD CONSTRAINT PK_instructor PRIMARY KEY (id);


CREATE TABLE specified_instruments_instructor (
 instructor_id INT NOT NULL,
 specified_instruments_instructor VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE specified_instruments_instructor ADD CONSTRAINT PK_specified_instruments_instructor PRIMARY KEY (instructor_id);

ALTER TABLE specified_instruments_instructor ADD CONSTRAINT FK_specified_instruments_instructor_0 FOREIGN KEY (instructor_id) REFERENCES instructor (id);



INSERT INTO instructor(ensemble_proficiency, person_number, first_name, last_name)
  VALUES
    ('Yes', '294321423191', 'Ingrid', 'Floyd');


INSERT INTO specified_instruments_instructor(specified_instruments_instructor)
VALUES
  ('Guitar');
```

What im wondering is why im getting this error:

```
ERROR:  Failing row contains (null, Guitar).null value in column "instructor_id" of relation "specified_instruments_instructor" violates not-null constraint 

ERROR:  null value in column "instructor_id" of relation "specified_instruments_instructor" violates not-null constraint
SQL state: 23502
Detail: Failing row contains (null, Guitar).
```

I thought that the SERIAL data type inserted the IDs during the insertion of a table, I have also tried INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL but have gotten the same result.

Comment: Well it *does* work as you expect for the `id SERIAL`. It does not work for `instructor_id INT`.

Comment: Yes so do I have to somehow get that ID from the id SERIAL to the instructor_id INT? Is there a general solution for that, or do I have to have some type of condition like:

INSERT INTO specified_instruments_instructor(instructor_id, specified_instruments_instructor)
VALUES
  ((INSERT INTO person (first_name) VALUES ('Ingrid')), 'Guitar');